# R Leaflet ClickEvent unable to find layerId

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am creating a leaflet map displaying different areas of local councils using polygons. I have created a shiny app that renders this leaflet output and registers click events. These click events will save lat, long and id so they can be matched against an identical data frame and used to call summary stats:

ie click on council area x on the map and it returns the name of that click event as a string which will then be used to grab matching summary stats from a data table with more extensive aggregate information.

I am attempting to assign each polygon a unique ID based on the input info which is in the form of a large spatial polygons data frame.

```
bins <- c(2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000, Inf)
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = map_data$rank, bins = bins)

# Plot mean SIMD rank for each council area
map <- leaflet(map_data) %>% 
  setView(-3.2008, 55.9452, 7) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", 
                   options= providerTileOptions(opacity = 0.99)) %>% 
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(rank),
              layerId = ~map_data$names, # Here is the layerId
              weight = 2,
              opacity = 1,
              color = "white",
              dashArray = "3",
              fillOpacity = 0.7,
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                weight = 2,
                color = "#666",
                dashArray = "",
                fillOpacity = 0.7,
                bringToFront = TRUE),
              label=~paste(map_data$names, 
                           round(map_data$rank)),
              labelOptions = labelOptions(textsize = "15px",
                                          direction = "auto"))
```

The shiny server calls this as:

```
observeEvent(input$map_click, {

        click <- input$map_click

        print(click$id)
}
```

Using this approach it can print out the lat and long of the click event to the console but outputs NULL for the id.

I am confused by this as calling data$names works fine for labels as you can see in the function above. The names are all unique.

Comment: If you use the "one side formula"  way of providing the layerId (meaning the use of `~`) you should call the variable name only, like `layerId = ~names`. That should work. THe other way around is getting rid of the tilde, like `layerId = map_data$names`

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help but I am afraid this didn't fix the issue. I've tried every conceivable combination of titles and tilde but the id is still simply outputting NULL.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It's strange as I have been using addPolygons like that lot of times. If you can provide a test data to play I think it would be easy to debug the problem.

Comment: So I was following Jlija Hansense tutorial at: https://medium.swirrl.com/interactive-maps-with-linked-data-and-r-e977ea441cb?gi=81e47771878f. 

It's a great tutorial for showing how to shade leaflet polygons based on a given variable but I'm having trouble taking it to the next step.

Comment: Ok, I should saw it earlier :( sorry. You are calling `click <- input$map_click` which returns the info for the map click. But you want the info for the polygon, that is a *shape*. You should call `click <- input$map_shape_click` and there you have the id info, at least with the tutorial data. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) for all the inputs availbale for shiny leaflet maps.

Comment: That fixed it - thanks!